# group pandas dataframe while averaging values in some columns

Tags: python, pandas

```
Country                        Region           Hemisphere     Crop Years  \
18  United States Of America  Temperate  Northern hemisphere    Maize  2011   
22  United States Of America  Temperate  Northern hemisphere    Maize  2015   
7                  Argentina  Temperate  Southern hemisphere  Soybean  2010   
2                  Argentina  Temperate  Southern hemisphere  Soybean  2002   
5                  Argentina  Temperate  Southern hemisphere    Maize  2010   
11  United States Of America  Temperate  Northern hemisphere  Soybean  2010   

                    Actual                             Predicted      error  \
18                      8.856633                         8.709798   1.657906   
22                     10.277621                        10.646027   3.584548   
7                       2.903666                         2.528243  12.929296   
2                       2.604214                         2.308457  11.356881   
5                       7.787116                         6.045908  22.360111   
11                      2.898108                         2.833479   2.230042   

     f-score  
18  0.574185  
22  0.711111  
7   0.189560  
2   0.269231  
5   0.709091  
11  0.627960
```

I want to summarize the sample dataframe above by crop while averaging values by year. I am doing this:

```
df[['Actual', 'Predicted']].groupby(df[['Crop', 'Years']]).mean()
```

However, I get this error:
*** ValueError: Grouper for '' not 1-dimensional

How to fix this?

Comment: Did you mean `df[['Actual', 'Predicted']].groupby(['Crop', 'Years']).mean()`?

Comment: @COLDSPEED, if I do that I get this error: `*** KeyError: 'Crop'`

Comment: Uh, that's not a related error. You have whitespaces. Try `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df[['Actual', 'Predicted']]` only has two columns (`Actual` and `Predicted`), so you cannot group that dataframe by `Crop` and `Years`.

I think that you first need to group by crop and years and then select the columns that you want to calculate the mean for:

```
df.groupby(['Crop', 'Years'])[['Actual', 'Predicted']].mean()
```